# How to create frequency table under couple conditions in r?

Tags: r, aggregate, conditional-statements, frequency

I am a rookie in R. I think my questions are basic ones. I want to know the frequency of a variable under couple conditions. I try to use table() but it does not work. I have searched a lot, I still cannot find the answers.

My data looks like this

```
ID AGE LEVEL End_month
1  14  1     201005
2  25  2     201006
3  17  2     201006
4  16  1     201008
5  19  3     201007
6  33  2     201008
7  17  2     201006
8  15  3     201005
9  23  1     201004
10 25  2     201007
```

I want to know two things.

First, I want to know the frequency of age under different level. The age shows in certain range and aggregate the rest as a variable. It looks like this.

```
          level 
          1 2 3 sum
age 14    1 0 0 1
    16    1 0 0 1
    15    0 0 1 1
    17    0 2 0 2
    19    0 0 1 1
    20+   1 3 0 4
sum       3 5 2 10
```

Second, I want to know the frequency of different age in different end_month of level 2&3 customer. I want to get a table like this.

For level 2 customer

```
         End_month
         201004 201005 201006 201007 201008 sum
age  15  0      0      0      0      0      0
     19  0      0      0      0      0      0
     17  0      0      2      0      0      2
     19  0      0      0      0      0      0
     25  0      0      0      1      0      1
     33  0      0      0      1      1      2
sum      0      0      2      2      1      5
```

For level 3 customer

```
         End_month
         201004 201005 201006 201007 201008 sum
age  15  0      1      0      0      0      1
     19  0      0      0      1      0      1
     17  0      0      0      0      0      0
     19  0      0      0      0      0      0
     25  0      0      0      0      0      0
     33  0      0      0      0      0      0
sum      0      1      0      1      0      2
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still achieve this with `table`, because it can take more than one variables.

For example, use

```
table(AGE, LEVEL)
```

to get the first two-way table.

Now, when you want to produce such table for each subset according to `LEVEL`, you can do it this way, assuming we are going for level 1:

```
subset <- LEVEL == 1
table(AGE[subset], END[subset])
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I get the frequency result of level2 and level3. I am so happy.

Comment: May I ask another following question. If I want to use a range of condition, how do I write it? It does not seem work by the following code. Thanks
`subset <- LEVEL == 1~2
table(AGE[subset], END[subset])`